# Nuxt js - Fresh install of nuxt 2.14.6 contains babel "loose option" warnings

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, babeljs

I have a fresh install of nuxt version 2.14.6 and I would like to silence an error I get when I run the nuxt command:

```
 WARN  Though the "loose" option was set to "false" in your @babel/preset-env co
The "loose" option must be the same for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties,
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { "loose": true }]
to the "plugins" section of your Babel config.
```

I'm assuming I need to override the babel config in my nuxt.config.js file, but I haven't found any helpful solutions.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Add the following to your `nuxt.config.js` file under the `build` section.

**nuxt.config.js**

```js
build: {
  babel:{
    plugins: [
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods', { loose: true }]
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Feel free to check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68663581/latest-nuxt-v2-15-7-install-with-babel-loose-option-warnings or in this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67466363/8816585 @Anthony

Answer (score 31):

Try add these in nuxt.config.js:

```js
build: {
  babel:{
    plugins: [
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", { "loose": true }],
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { "loose": true }],
      ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object", { "loose": true }]
    ]
  }  
},
```

Comment: `@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object` is enough, no need to have all of them.

Comment: Thank you. I am using nuxt@2.14.0 and getting the same warnings littering the console. Listing all of the plugins like this worked for me whereas only listing `@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object` did not.

Answer (score 18):

I'd rather reset `nuxt` back to `2.15.2` and wait until it's fixed. While the above answer fixes it in the short run, those warnings on a fresh nuxt install look like a bug to me.

Comment: Upvoted. It's always good to make sure you aren't silencing something you might actually care about, without fully understanding the ramifications. 

Don't mind me while I add this to my Babel config for now though...  :D

Comment: Np, just wanted to add for completeness and for others.

Comment: Why? The current behavior is a bug (warnings on a fresh install), and it's a solution until a fixed version is available.

Comment: Alright I got the point. It wasn't primarily meant to be a critique to the proposed solution but more of an alternative. But it's up to moderators to decide.

Comment: It seems to be fixed with 2.15.5. cheerio .

Comment: It's just the mods having a power trip, as per usual on SO. This answer was vital to me frankly

Answer (score 8):

#### More recent update for Nuxt 2.15.7

It looks like some errors are back again with the latest release, more info can be found here [Latest Nuxt v2.15.7 install with babel "loose" option warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68663581/8816585)

---

This ons is fixed from Nuxt `v2.15.5` as stated in this github issue: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/9224#issuecomment-835742221

You can remove any `resolutions` and `build.babel.plugins` related to this bug in your `nuxt.config.js` configuration. Also, if needed you should reset:

- `yarn.lock` (or `package-lock.json`)
- `node_modules/.cache`
- `.nuxt`

Answer (score 3):

**package.json** (When my packages were as under)

```json
"dependencies": {
  "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
  "core-js": "^3.15.1",
  "nuxt": "^2.15.7",
  "vuetify": "^2.5.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.12.1"
}
```

**nuxt.config.js** (Following helped me)

```js
build: {
  babel: {
    plugins: [
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object', { loose: true }]
    ],
  },
}
```

Comment: Is is happening if the `nuxt` version is between `2.15.5` and `2.15.7`.

Comment: Valid answer for `nuxt: 2.15.7`

Answer (score 0):

For me, setting this in the `package.json` file worked,

```
"resolutions": {
  "@babel/core": "7.13.15",
  "@babel/preset-env": "7.13.15"
}
```

Run yarn install afresh to install the packages