# Nuxt.Js axios not using baseURL despite it being set correctly

Tags: javascript, axios, nuxt.js

I want to call an API in `asyncData()`

```js
  async asyncData({ $axios, params, store }) {
    let itemUUID = params.item;
    let item = await $axios.get("/item/" + itemUUID);
    return {item};
  }
```

**Problem:** Axios is still making the request on `http://localhost:3000`
if I do a `console.log($axios.defaults.baseURL)` the correct baseURL of my API is printed.
This also works if I use my store action & make the call by using `this.$axios`

I am using *@nuxtjs/axios 5.13.1* with *Nuxt 2.15.6* in SSR mode and configured it with the correct baseURL in the `nuxt.config.js`

**Interestingly,** if I edit my page content and a hot module reload is triggered, the correct URL is used. Maybe the question should be if Axios is triggered in the right time, on the server?

**Edit**: I checked the request that was made on HMR and this was triggered in the client.js.
If I call my store inside the `created()` hook the request gets executed successfully.

My `nuxt.config.js`:

```
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    axios: {
      baseURL: process.env.EXPRESS_SERVER_URL
    }
  },

  privateRuntimeConfig: {
    axios: {
      baseURL: process.env.EXPRESS_SERVER_URL,
    }
  },
```

Comment: What if you `console.log($axios)` in `asyncData`? How did you configured the `baseURL` in `nuxt.config.js`? `asyncData` and `fetch` (the hook) should produce the same result (server + client). Did you restarted your app after the `baseURL` update?

Comment: Still includes the correct baseURL configured in nuxt.config.js - this contains an axios object holding `baseURL: process.env.EXPRESS_SERVER_URL`

Comment: Maybe try to use the `runtimeConfig` for the axios configuration, as suggested in the official docs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67983038/8816585

Comment: I did. check my edited question

Comment: What if you call it entirely server side? Like at the top of your `nuxt.config.js` file, like a regular Node.js script? Does it reach the proper endpoint?

Comment: I am exporting my config so I cannot call a method directly in there (I guess?). But I put everything in a `async fetch()` block which results in the correct URL being logged, but I also see an `Error in fetch(): Error: unable to verify the first certificate`. (Sometimes, at least)
As stated in the config `fetch()` also gets executed on route navigation. This works correctly and fetches results correct. No certificate errors on the client side.

Comment: Ah yeah, right. Try it in `nuxtServerInit` so: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action

Comment: That worked. calling `await this.$axios.get(...)` seems to fetch the stuff. Of course only when using NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 in my .env

Now, doing the same in my component also works (TLS disabled) in fetch(). So it must be the TLS thing going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR;** This was not related at all - I forgot to set the auth token for my backend. At the time of axios init it's not present. $axios object doesn't have auth - backend fails.

On page load the nuxt function `nuxtServerInit()` is used to get the auth token out of the `acces_token` cookie.

I am using a plugin to initialize Axios - with the token from the store.
But of couse the token is not present at the time axios is initialized as **nuxtServerInit is called after plugin init**.

In my `axios.js` plugin I changed:

```
export default function({ app, error: nuxtError, store }) {
  const token = const token = store.state.user.token;

  app.$axios.setToken(token, "Bearer");
}
```

to;

```
export default function({ app, error: nuxtError, store }) {
  const token = app.$cookies.get("access_token");

  app.$axios.setToken(token, "Bearer");
}
```

Now the token is present & used for every request happening server-side.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is the `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` thing doing but your frontend configuration (Nuxt) is working well so far.

Sorry if I cannot help on the Express part.

Maybe try to setup HTTPS locally on Nuxt: [How to run NUXT (npm run dev) with HTTPS in localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56966137/how-to-run-nuxt-npm-run-dev-with-https-in-localhost/57895543#57895543)

Comment: Sadly that's only the half answer as disabling TLS is not an option. My question was probably wrong for that error you got me to find out. Thanks for that! :)
I probably will have to fix the root certificate on the server first.