# Nuxt3 - `_nuxt`-directory not found (404) on GitHub Pages

Tags: nuxt.js, github-actions, github-pages, nuxtjs3, mjs

(I know it might sound similar to [missing js files from _nuxt folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67977235/missing-js-files-from-nuxt-folder), but unfortunately, I was not able to understand the answer from there)

When I deploy my `dist`-folder to GitHub Pages, it contains

```
dist 
| _nuxt
  | css/main.css
  | entry.*******.css
  | entry-*******.mjs
  | index-*******.mjs
  | history-********.mjs
  | header-********.mjs
  | ... some other mjs-files
| css/main.css
| index.html
| history.html
| ... some other HTML-files
```

The HTML-pages are served, perfectly fine, and in the `<head>`-section, they want to load the modules (`.mjs`-files). All of these requests, unfortunately, fail with a 404:

[image: Chrome console error I]
[image: Chrome console error II]

Why do the requests to the `_nuxt`-folder fail, while `/` and `/css` requests go through?

---

Edit: Just seen that in VS Code, this folder is just marked as a **symlink to the `.output/public`-folder** (generated by `nuxi generate`):

[image].

Might that be the issue? But appears that it contains the files, anyway:

[image]

---

Edit II:
I cannot run `npm run start` for local tests (`node .output/server/index.mjs`), because the `.output/server` folder is empty, as can be seen on the image:

[image]

When running the folder in Live Server (VS Code extension), the errors return:

[image]

---

Actually, after downloading the generated `.tar`-file (the artifact that is generated automatically by `GitHub Actions` for deployment) does not include the `_nuxt`-directory, but just the static HTML-files and `css`-directory as well as an `assets` dir with `assets/css/main.css`-file in it. Why is the `_nuxt`-directory ignored by the GitHub Action?

Comment: Does it work locally once built?

Comment: No, not through running `npm run start` (`node .output/server/index.mjs`), since the `.output/server`-folder is empty, only `output/public` folder has files in it, which are the same as in `dist` (=> symbolic link?), see Edit II

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As told [here](https://alex-alekseichuk.github.io/2020/06/10/nojekyll-file-to-host-nuxt-on-github/)

> It is now possible to completely bypass Jekyll processing on GitHub Pages by creating a file named .nojekyll in the root of your pages repo and pushing it to GitHub. This should only be necessary if your site uses files or directories that start with underscores since Jekyll considers these to be special resources and does not copy them to the final site.

This might answer the question, since the `_nuxt`-directory is prefixed with an underscore, it will be ignored by Jekyll builds. This means, adding a `.nojekyll`-file, should solve the issue, according to [GitHub Blog](https://github.blog/2009-12-29-bypassing-jekyll-on-github-pages/).

The `.nojekyll`-file will obviously have to be placed in the directory that is deployed, in my case, since I am only deploying `dist`, it needed to be in nuxt's `public`-folder to be included in the `dist`-directory.

Comment: Please do not post link-only but actual text. Links can 404.

Answer (score 1):

Add `.nojekyll` empty file to the `public` folder and run `npm run generate`.

Add the below snippet to `defineNuxtConfig` config

```js
  target: 'static',
  router: {
    base: '/ repo name /', //eg:- /crstnmac.github.io/
  },
```

Use the below script to deploy your nuxt website to github pages

`"deploy": "push-dir --dir=dist --branch=gh-pages --cleanup"`

Answer (score 1):

### Use `.nojekyll` *and* `-t true`

To deploy Nuxt3 (or any other project that happens to have folders starting with underscore, ie `_nuxt`) I had to do the below steps. For reference, previously Nuxt2's `generate` would make the `.nojekyll` file for you.

**1. Create an empty file `.nojekyll` in the `public` folder**

This inhibits Jekyll processing on Github pages, which then allows the `_nuxt` folder to make it to the final destination.

**2. Use the flag `-t true` in the `gh-pages` command**

package.json:

```
`"deploy": "gh-pages -d dist -t true"`
```

Without this flag, my `.nojekyll` file wasn't being deployed, even though it was in my public folder locally! You can confirm this by going to your Github repo (in a web browser) and change to the branch you're attempting to use as your gh-pages branch. Above, I'm using `dist` as my gh-pages branch.