# Latest Nuxt v2.15.7 install with babel "loose" option warnings

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, babeljs

I've created a brand new project with `npx create-nuxt-app my-cool-project` but I do have some errors when running `yarn dev`.

> Though the "loose" option was set to "false" in your @babel/preset-env config, it will not be used for @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object since the "loose" mode option was set to "true" for @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods.
> The "loose" option must be the same for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties, @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods and @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object (when they are enabled): you can silence this warning by explicitly adding
> ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object", { "loose": true }]
> to the "plugins" section of your Babel config.

Do you have any idea about this one? It reminds me of this other issue: [Nuxt js - Fresh install of nuxt 2.14.6 contains babel "loose option" warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67350359/8816585)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This issue is indeed back as shown in this Github issue

https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/9224#issuecomment-893263501

This happens if your Nuxt version is between `2.15.5` and `2.15.7` (I think).

A temporary solution could be adding this to your `nuxt.config.js` file, as suggested [here](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/9224#issuecomment-893224842)

```js
build: {
  babel: {
    plugins: [
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
      '@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods',

      // or with JUST the line below 
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object', { loose: true }]
    ],
  },
}
```

A definitive fix will probably be shipped shortly, feel free to subscribe to the Github issue to be notified of the latest updates.

---

EDIT: This will be fixed once this PR is merged and there's a new release: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/pull/9631

Answer (score 4):

As for me helps this modification on answer above:

```
yarn add --dev @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object
```

Then change `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
build: {
  babel:{
    plugins: [
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: true }],
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods', { loose: true }],
      ['@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object', { loose: true }]
    ]
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I just did yarn add "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods" and the warnings disappeared

Comment: The issue might have been fixed for 3 years indeed. Anyway, you should use Nuxt3.