# Nuxt throws 'The "path" argument must be of type string' or console spam

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, babeljs

## What I'm doing & what's wrong

I'm working on a new project ([GitHub repo](https://github.com/AnonymousX86/jakub-suchenek)) and when I'm trying to run a local dev server I'm getting this error:

```
> jakub-suchenek@1.1.0 dev
> nuxt


   ╭───────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                       │
   │   Nuxt @ v2.15.7                      │
   │                                       │
   │   ▸ Environment: development          │
   │   ▸ Rendering:   server-side          │
   │   ▸ Target:      server               │
   │                                       │
   │   Listening: http://localhost:3000/   │
   │                                       │
   ╰───────────────────────────────────────╯

i Preparing project for development                                                                           19:29:23
i Initial build may take a while                                                                              19:29:23
i Discovered Components: .nuxt/components/readme.md                                                           19:29:23
√ Builder initialized                                                                                         19:29:23

 ERROR  The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined                                        19:29:23

  at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
  at validateString (node:internal/validators:119:11)
  at Object.extname (node:path:837:5)
  at node_modules\@nuxt\builder\dist\builder.js:413:98
  at Array.map (<anonymous>)
  at Builder.normalizePlugins (node_modules\@nuxt\builder\dist\builder.js:409:28)
  at async Builder.generateRoutesAndFiles (node_modules\@nuxt\builder\dist\builder.js:371:31)
  at async Builder.build (node_modules\@nuxt\builder\dist\builder.js:319:5)
  at async Object._buildDev (node_modules\@nuxt\cli\dist\cli-dev.js:107:5)
  at async Object.startDev (node_modules\@nuxt\cli\dist\cli-dev.js:65:7)
  at async Object.run (node_modules\@nuxt\cli\dist\cli-dev.js:52:5)
  at async NuxtCommand.run (node_modules\@nuxt\cli\dist\cli-index.js:413:7)
```

But this occurs only when I have this in my `nuxt.config.js` file:

```js
plugins: [ "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object", { "loose": true }],
```

Without this plugin config, I have **A LOT** of spam in the console.

```js
plugins: [],
```

A **few hundred** times:

```
 WARN  Though the "loose" option was set to "false" in your @babel/preset-env config, it will not be used for @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object since the "loose" mode option was set to "true" for @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods.
The "loose" option must be the same for @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties, @babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods and @babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object (when they are enabled): you can silence this warning by explicitly adding
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object", { "loose": true }]
to the "plugins" section of your Babel config.
```

## What I've tried

1. Changing Nuxt.js version (`2.15`, `2.14`, `2.13`).
2. Reinstalling node packages.

## My question

What is the best solution for this? To do not have console spam with "WARN" and have a working app.

Or is there no solution? According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68663581/latest-nuxt-v2-15-7-install-with-babel-loose-option-warnings), for now there's no way to do not have these awful WARN errors in the console.

---

## My code:

(open-sourced on GitHub)

- [`nuxt.config.js`](https://github.com/AnonymousX86/jakub-suchenek/blob/master/nuxt.config.js)
- [`package.json`](https://github.com/AnonymousX86/jakub-suchenek/blob/master/package.json)

Answer (score 2):

This is a new bug that is already fixed and pending to be released.

More info can be found here: [Latest Nuxt v2.15.7 install with babel "loose" option warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68663581/8816585)

Comment: I've already mentioned it in the post but thanks for the quick response.

Comment: The solution is given there in terms of configuration.