# How to downgrade the version of Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I created a nuxt project, but I get a lot of warnings, which you can read about here:

[Nuxt js - Fresh install of nuxt 2.14.6 contains babel "loose option" warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67350359/nuxt-js-fresh-install-of-nuxt-2-14-6-contains-babel-loose-option-warnings?noredirect=1&lq=1)

And now I want to create a project not with the latest version, but with the previous version 2.15.2

How can i do this?

Comment: But that's just a warning and You can mutate it by the fixes that people posted in the link You've added. Nothing wrong with the newest Nuxt, it's not the problem.
Better keep up to date. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some [security concerns](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/9284) with the previous versions, you better remove those warnings and keep an up to date version.
Here is how to fix those warning: [Latest Nuxt v2.15.7 install with babel "loose" option warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68663581/8816585)

Otherwise, if you want to use an older version of Nuxt, you could edit the `package.json`, set it like `"nuxt": "2.15.2",` and run `yarn` again (or `npm i` if using NPM).